# Crystal reports Crosstab vs2010: Averaging Data

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, crosstab

Good Day.

I am using Crystal reports that is supplied for Visual Studio 2010.

I have several cross tab report objects in a report summery that all get their data from the same database table. In this table I have an initial mass, the current mass,the number of days between the start and current mass readings and the average daily gain per animal [(current mass - start mass)/Days]. I have a record per animal in the table.

In the crosstab i am showing the average start mass, the average current mass, the average days and the average ADG (average daily gain). The problem I am having is that the Average of the ADG is not calculated correctly. What is required is  [(Total current mass - Total start mass)/Total Days].

I have tried adding this in as a formula but I show different summaries of the data the ADG values do not adapt to the crosstab view.

How can I add a formula to the cross tab control to do the calculation in the control and not as a formula field that is added to the cross tab (as that does not give the required answer)

http://www.beeftech.co.za/download/Sample.pdf for sample report page

Comment: you add a new column to crosstab and write your formula there?

Comment: Siva, Could you add a little more detail as to how to do this? When I try what you suggested it give me the result as the column header. This is not what I am looking for. I would like the result to show as per the sample linked, but with the correct answer in the Average ADG row. Looking at the first cross tab on the linked report, the result is 0.45. (366.58-247.69)/310.59 should give me 0.38. If I use the Median in place of the average for the ADG I get 0.369, which is closer but also not correct.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry didn't read your requirement correctly.

Since the data you are getting from database is wrong you want to calculate manually. In this case follow below process.

1. Here you need to add a row to the existing crosstab and insert calculation. Set summarized field lables to `summarize vertically`.
2. Now insert `Embeeded summary`. This will insert a row for you and inthat write your formula and supress other rows that are not required.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please take a look at the link in the original question for a sample of what the cross tab looks like. The fields mentioned in your answer are rows, not columns in the cross tab. The link again is http://www.beeftech.co.za/download/Sample.pdf.